# Render PDF from buffer using Node.js and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, handlebars.js

I have my `files` object on back-end:

```
[{ Id: 3,
  UserId: 7,
  FileType: 'application/pdf',
  FileContent:
   <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 33 0d 0a 25 e2 e3 cf d3 0d 0a 0d 0a 31 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0d 0a 3c 3c 0d 0a 2f 54 79 70 65 20 2f 43 61 74 61 6c 6f 67 0d 0a 2f 4f ... >,
  FileName: '1',
  UserUploadId: 7 },
...]
```

I am sending this object to the view:

```
res.render('dashboard/files/index',{'title': 'My files', 'my_files' : files})
```

On HTML I am rendering with `handlebarsjs` a table containing a row per file and a button that executes a function receiving as unique parameter the file `Id`

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">UserId</th>
            <th scope="col">View</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each my_files}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{this.UserId}}</td>
            <td>
                <button onclick="viewPdf({{this.Id}})"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the same document, with JavaScript, I am trying to get the `FileContent` property of the object, but for this I need to find the file in the array `my_files` searching by `Id` parameter.

```
<script>
    function viewPdf(Id){
        var found_file = my_files.find(function(element) {
            return element.Id == Id;
        });

        console.log(found_file)
    }
</script>
```

But I am getting this error output:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: my_files is not defined
>       at viewPdf (......:465)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: my_files seems not declared, try to fetch data in the function `if (typeof my_files === "undefined")`

Comment: `typeof my_files` -> `"undefined"`

Comment: Make a server call on the function after the if statement or declare my_files as global variable

Comment: The weird thing is: the table is being rendered with `my_files` information, but when I click the button and I try to find by `Id` on the array, `my_files` seems to be undefined

Comment: If the variable is scoped in a function or an object, you can't retrieve it just by "my_files". If you can find where my_files is stored, you could retrieve it after. If you don't see where my_files is, pass it in arguments function or make a server call ;)

Comment: So where is `handlebarjs` storing `my_files` object? It can access the object because it renders the table without any problem, so why I can't access to it too from javascript?

Comment: handlebarjs works server side, so you can't retrieve it in the client.

Comment: And is there other way I can append to javascript `document` scope `my_files` object?

Comment: You can make a server call after the document is loaded and stored my_files as global variable or fetch a local object directly in the function viewPdf

Comment: You mean I can make ajax query on `viewPdf`function and bring the object again to the scope?

Comment: Yes, you can make an ajax IN viewPdf `$.ajax('/getThoseFiles', success:data=>...)`

Comment: Thanks, you can explain it as answer, I would be glad to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,

JavaScript running server and browser side is different. You can't find a declared server side variable in the browser, vice versa.

A way to shared variable between server and client :

```
function viewPdf(Id){
    $.ajax('/getFiles', {
        success:function(my_files){
            // put logic here
        }
    })
}
```